# What is a phenomenon?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, definitions

According to philosophy ,what is a phenomenon ? And does that definition include mental phenomenons as well? Lastly , is there anything which is not a phenomenon?

Comment: There's a whole lot of different philosophies that use the word "phenomenon" in distinct ways... which philosophy do you want to understand better?

Comment: Try to answer from popular perspectives if possible.